# Can rails engine override main application's routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I am writing a Rail 3 engine to add some marketplace functionality to an existing app. The existing app has an item description page and I am going to add some extra elements that will be used by the marketplace to that page. When the user visits the item page using the main app's route, I would like to use the engine's controller and view to render the page so that the new elements will be displayed. Effectively the engine will override some of the main application's routes. Can this be achieved?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea. In general, the application's routes override routes provided by the engine, not the other way 'round. If the engine is going to handle this functionality, why would you want the application to still have those routes?

Comment: @MrTheWalrus, my problem is that the website I am writing the engine for has open sourced the whole system but my engine won't be open sourced. The engine won't be available to other websites that are powered by the same system.  If I can't override the main app's path, I'll have to modify their ops code, which I don't want. But I guess that will be the easy way out.